# Storing and accessing data for future analysis of intra and inter-operator variability

Tags: perl, r, postgresql

I'm am about to start a short project which will involve a reasonable amount of data which I would like to store in a sensible manner - preferably a postgressql database.

I will give a quick outline of the task.  I will be processing and analysing data for a series of images each of which will have a unique ID. For each image, myself and other operators will complete some simple image processing tasks including adjusting angles and placing regions with the end result being numerous quantitative parameters - eg mean, variance etc. We expect there will be intra and inter-operator variability in these measures which is what I would like to analyse.

My initial plan was to store the data in the following way

```
ID   Operator   Attempt    Date     Result1     Result2      Reconstruction Method    Iterations 
1    AB         1          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
1    AB         2          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
1    CD         1          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
1    CD         2          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
2    AB         1          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
2    AB         2          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
2    CD         1          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
2    CD         2          01/01/13   x         x            FBP
1    AB         1          11/01/13   x         x            FBP
1    AB         2          01/01/13   x         x            MLEM
```

Now what I would like to compare (using correlation and Bland Altman plots) are the difference in results for the same operator processing the same image (the images must have the same ID, Date, Reconstruction technique) for all operators. i.e for all identical image and operator how do attempt 1 and 2 differ. I want to do the same analysis for interoperator variability i.e how does AB compare to CD for ID 1 for all images reconstructed with FBP or EF to AB for all images reconstructed with MLEM.  Images with the same unique ID but acquired on different dates or reconstruction techniques should not be compared as they will contain difference outwith operator variability.

I have various R scripts to do the analysis but what I am uncertain of is how to access my data and arrange it in a sensible format to carry out the analysis or if my planned storage method is optimum for doing so. In the past I have used perl to access the database and pull out the numbers but I have recently discovered Rpostgressql which may be more suitable.

I guess my question is, for such a database how can I pick out:

(a) all unique images (ID, acquired on same date with same reconstruction method) and compare the difference in all Result1 for operator AB (CD etc) for attempt 1 and 2

(b) the same thing comparing all Result1 attempt 1s between AB and CD, CD and EF etc

Here is an example of the output I would like for (a)

```
ID   Operator    Date     Result1 (Attempt 1)    Result1(Attempt 2)
1    AB          01/01/13     10                      12
2    AB          01/01/13     22                      21
3    AB          03/01/13     15                      17
4    AB          04/01/13     27                      25
5    AB          06/01/13     14                      12
1    AB          11/01/13     3                       6
```

I would then analyse the last 2 columns

An example output for (b) comparing AB and CD

```
ID   Date     Result1 (Op: AB, Att: 1)    Result1(Op: CD: Att 1)
1    01/01/13        10                          12
2    01/01/13        22                          21
3    05/01/13        12                          14
1    11/01/13        19                          24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just a rough idea!

> (a) all unique images (ID, acquired on same date with same
>   reconstruction method) and compare the difference in all Result1 for
>   operator AB (CD etc) for attempt 1 and 2

For (a) you can use SQL statements that make use of the arguments, `DISTINCT` & `SORT BY`.

#### For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT Images FROM YourTable SORT BY DATE(Date), "Reconstruction Method"
```

> (b) the same thing comparing all Result1 attempt 1s between AB and CD,
>   CD and EF etc

For (b) you can use SQL statements that make use of the argument, `WHERE`.

#### For example

```
SELECT * From YourTable WHERE Operator=AB
```